# Oracle SQL Count of Sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the Count of a sum using a case statement and I am getting the below error -

`not a single-group function`

Is it possible to do the count of a Sum?

**count(case when sum(ern.hours) >0 then 1 end)**

Comment: Create a cte with results of (case when sum(ern.hours) >0 then 1 end) and use this value to apply count(cte.colname)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  The expression makes no sense.

Comment: **Please** show complete SQL statement, table definitions.

Comment: How can I attach a file?  SQL statement is too long?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `SUM(ern.hours)` in a subquery and then do the following:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN hours_sum > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

An example:

```
SELECT row_a, row_b, SUM(CASE WHEN hours_sum > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM
  (SELECT row_a, row_b, sum(ern.hours) AS hours_sum
  FROM table_name AS ern
  GROUP BY row_a, row_b) sub_q
GROUP BY row_a, row_b;
```

Comment: Next time, just use the Edit button to make changes in your answer instead of deleting it and adding another one.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to do something like what you are showing. But is that really what you ARE trying to do?

Here is an example based on the EMP table in the SCOTT schema. The table shows 14 employees (14 rows) in three departments. I will count in how many departments the sum of commissions is greater than zero:

```
select   count(case when sum(comm) > 0 then 1 end) as depts_with_commissions
from     scott.emp
group by deptno
;

DEPTS_WITH_COMMISSIONS
----------------------
                     1
```

I don't see the query throwing an error on this. Perhaps you are selecting OTHER things also, in the same `SELECT` clause?

The result is correct: only employees in Dept 30 have commissions.

```
select   empno, ename, deptno, comm
from     scott.emp
order by deptno, comm
;

     EMPNO ENAME          DEPTNO       COMM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK              10           
      7839 KING               10           
      7934 MILLER             10           
      7566 JONES              20           
      7902 FORD               20           
      7876 ADAMS              20           
      7369 SMITH              20           
      7788 SCOTT              20           
      7844 TURNER             30          0
      7499 ALLEN              30        300
      7521 WARD               30        500
      7654 MARTIN             30       1400
      7900 JAMES              30           
      7698 BLAKE              30
```

Comment: Thank You.  I will take a closer look at my SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(count(1)) MGR_WITH_MORE_THAN_1_SUB
  from scott.emp
 group by mgr
having count(1) > 1;

MGR_WITH_MORE_THAN_1_SUB
------------------------
                       3
```

It counts the number of managers with more than 1 direct subordinates, but it relies on a quirk of nested aggregate functions.

While this one

```
select count(sum(comm)) DEPTS_WITH_COMMISSIONS
  from scott.emp
 group by DEPTNO
having sum(comm) > 0;

DEPTS_WITH_COMMISSIONS
----------------------
                     1
```

Counts departments with commissions greater than 0 using the same quirk.